# Reverse of ascii function in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ascii

When I do following query

```
select asciistr(first_name) from person where id = 1
```

the result contains `'\200D'`.

So what is the reverse function of converting a `'\200D'` to character, so I can find all names with that specific character.

Comment: what us the value of first_name?  That looks like a UTF-16 code unit.  What language is the database defined with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\200D` is the [U+200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER](https://codepoints.net/U+200D)

If you like to find names with this (non printable) character try

```
SELECT *
FROM person
WHERE first_name LIKE '%'||UNISTR('\200D')||'%'
```

or

```
WHERE asciistr(first_name) LIKE '%\200D%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `UNISTR` (and, maybe, `CAST` it to a `VARCHAR2`). If you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person ( first_name, id ) AS
SELECT 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT CAST( UNISTR( '\200D' ) AS VARCHAR2(20) ), 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Then the output from your query:

```sql
select first_name,
       asciistr(first_name)
from   person
where  id = 1
```

Is:

> ```
> FIRST_NAME | ASCIISTR(FIRST_NAME)
> :--------- | :-------------------
> A          | A                   
> ?          | \200D
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f486a3e0df3c7608a174396e62e4a473)*